# How does the first parameter affect the result of array.map( ) method?

Tags: ecmascript-6

I'm running this snippet in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/lupezigoqo/edit?js,console):

```
let array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16]
let array2=[1, 4, 9, 16]



const map1=array2.map(x=>x*2)
console.log(map1)
//Output is:[2, 8, 18, 32]


const map2 = array2.map((y,x) => x * 2)    
console.log(map2)
//Output is: [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

How is the first parameter affecting the output of map function?

**Edit:** Two precise answers. Just giving some context on why I asked this question. Thanks to SO, now I know that first parameter is value at the index, while second is the index of the array. I had seen this being used in an example: `map((_,x)=>itemName+=x)`. If I pass only one parameter, it'd turn it into `itemName+valueAtTheIndex`, however if I pass two arguments and use the second, it will turn into `itemName1,itemName2,.....`
Quite handy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your two snippets you call "`x`" two different things. In the first one `x` is the *first* argument of the function `array.map()`, which will contain each value, while in the second snippet `x` is the *second* argument and it will contain each array *index*.

In the first case `x` will contain the array values (which is what you expected) while in the second case `x` will contain the values 0,1,2,3, which yield the result you got.

The identifier `_` has no special meaning but it is a  valid argument identifier. you could have called it `y` and would have gotten the same result.

Comment: But if I call it with map(2,x) for example, nothing happens

Comment: You need a valid identifier to name the first argument. 2 is not a valid identifier name while _ is.

Comment: Ok. I used y as parameter, but result is same.

Comment: @SanSolo same as what? I don't understand exactly what you did and what result you obtained. The point is whether you use the first or the second parameter in your computation, the name is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

`_` is not affecting the output of `.map`. It's the argument you are using to do the calculation that's affecting the output.

`.map(entry, index)` is the syntax when you use two args in a `map` function.

```
let arr = [1, 4, 9, 16]

const ret = arr.map(x => x * 2)
console.log(ret)
// Output is: [2, 8, 18, 32]

// here, x is array index - 0, 1, 2, 3
const ret = arr.map((_, x) => x * 2)
console.log(ret)
// Output is: [0, 2, 4, 6]

// try it with `_`
// You'll get the desired output
const ret = arr.map((_, x) => _ * 2)
console.log(ret)
// Output is: [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

Comment: So second parameter is index, and first parameter is value at that index?

Comment: @SanSolo Yes. When you use one parameter, you are using only the value at the index and the second parameter is ignored. When you use two parameters, you can use both the value at the index and also the index.

Answer (score 1):

first argument in map function is the current value in your array while second column is index.

_ is used for ignoring the first column.

Comment: That makes sense, but if it is being ignored, why does it produce a different result?

Comment: You are running operation on the array index not on values.

In first, you used values and in second you used index i.e. 0,1,2,3 etc

Comment: thanks. I have reached vote limit today. I'll upvote your answer as soon as it resets